# Directional graph in prolog

Tags: prolog

I defined the edges, but how should I make it directional and get answers to all these questions.

[image: Assignment]

Comment: "only some useless outdated resources": what makes you believe that those were outdated? Problems like this have not changed in the last 4, 5 decades or so.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the book [*Thinking Recursively*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471816523), by Eric S. Roberts useful in learning Prolog. It's a great book, and recursion is at the heart of Prolog. But get it from the library, or buy it used, because it is stupidly expensive new.

A *directed* graph is a graph where the *edges* have a direction associated with them: If node *origin* is connected to node *destination*, you can travel from *origin* to *destination*, but not in reverse. The directionality is implied through convention. In your assignment's `edge/2`, the first argument, say `p(1,2)` is the *origin*, and the second argument, say `p(2,2)`, the *destination*. So...

```
edge( p(1,2), p(2:2) ).
```

An edge exists between `p(1,2)` and `p(2,2)` such that one can travel from `p(1,2)` to `p(2,2)`, but not in the other direction.

But it's all convention. There's no reason whatsoever you couldn't define the edges of a graph using additional arguments to indicate the directionality of the edge:

- `edge(a,b,>).`
  might indicate you can travel from `a` to `b` but not vice-versa, while
- `edge(a,b,<).`
  might indicate that you can travel **to** `a` **from** `b`, but not vice-versa, and
- `edge(a,b,<>).` might indicate bi-directional travel is possible.

So you can define the graph in question thus (I'm using `:`/2 because it's more concise and eliminates typing):

```
edge( 1:1, 2:2 ).
edge( 1:2, 2:2 ).
edge( 2:2, 3:1 ).
edge( 3:1, 2:1 ).
edge( 2:2, 2:3 ).
edge( 2:3, 3:3 ).
```

To traverse the graph is pretty simple (especially if you don't have to worry about cycles in the graph):

```
connected(A,B) :- % A and B are directly connected
  edge(A,B).      % - If you can get from A to B.
connected(A,B) :- % A and B are indirectly connected
  edge(A,X),      % - If A is directly connected to a node X
  connected(X,B). % - such that X is connected to B
```

That's about all there is to it.

If you want to know what route (the path) you took through the graph, it's not much more complicated — we just need to keep track of where we started and where we went:

```
connected(A,B,[A|P]) :-     % a path always starts with the origin
  connected_via(A,B, P ).   % - then invoke the helper predicate

connected_via(A,B,[B]) :-   % A is directly connected to B and the path ends with B
  edge(A,B).                % - if an edge exists between A and B.
connected_via(A,B,[X|P]) :- % A is  indirectly connected to B (and we add X to the path) 
  edge(A,X),                % - if an edge exists between A and some node X
  connected_via(X,B,P).     % - such that X is connected to B.
```